# Unsupported operand types in php

Tags: php

```html
if ($opt_selected=="y")
     {
        # code...
   
          $errorMessage = "";
         $phone = $_POST['phone'];
         $myString = $phone;
         $myArray = explode(',', $myString);
         print_r($myArray);

          if ($errorMessage != "" ) 
          {
                    echo "<p class='message'>" .$errorMessage. "</p>" ;
     
          }
              else

         {
             $max_id=mysqli_query($db,"select max(id) from batch");
             $row = mysqli_fetch_array($max_id);
      //error is for below line :Unsupported operand types                
                    $row=$row+1;

                     $res=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO batch(`id`,`phone`) VALUES (row,'$myArrays')");
                     
                     $delete = mysqli_query($db,'insert into to_numbers_hist select * from to_numbers');
                     $delete = mysqli_query($db,'delete from to_numbers');

            foreach ($myArrays as $myArray) {

              
                      
                   $ins="INSERT INTO `codexworld`.`to_numbers`(`batch_id`,`phone`)
            VALUES ('$id','$phone')";
            $test=mysqli_query($db,$ins) or die(mysqli_error($db));
            if($test)
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
            else
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
                     
            }
/
                  
         }
```

Here its giving error like this 
Unsupported operand types

so i'm not getting what to do ,please let me correct where i'm wrong

and the for-each loop is it correct no

here i'm entering number in text-box separated by comma ,by splitting those commas and storing into db with generating id we are referring this id in another table 
so what i need to do to overcome this problem,

//error is for below line :Unsupported operand types
                    $row=$row+1;

this line giving error

Comment: Its because `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row and not the numeric value.

Comment: `$row = $row + 1` should not work as $row now consist the query returned data. you need to use it like `$row = $row['returned_col'] + 1;`

Comment: `print_r(gettype($row));` will show you your issue

Answer (score 0):

Your `$row` variable contains an array as you return the data from MySQL using:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($max_id);
```

+1 is simply not available for an array. Instead create a variable like `$rc=0;` (for row count) and increment it in your loop.

It also doesn't make sense to do:

```
$res=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO batch(`id`,`phone`) VALUES (row,'$myArrays')");
```

Your `row` should most likely be called `$row` but then you would try to save an array into a numeric column, same applies for the `$myArrays` variable.

I would recommend to first get yourself familiar with [MySQL queries](http://php.net/mysql_query) and also take more care about good code quality before continuing on your project.

Comment: i did $row=0; but its giving error for foreach loop Notice: Undefined variable: myArrays in C:\xampp\htdocs\import_csv_file_into_mysql_php\importData.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined variable: myArrays in C:\xampp\htdocs\import_csv_file_into_mysql_php\importData.php on line 46

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\import_csv_file_into_mysql_php\importData.php on line 46

Comment: As pointed out by "Tomin B" in another post, you have some other errors in your code as well. I updated my answer to include some general recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

**$row** is a resultset . You cannot do $row +1 operation on a resultset

```
if ($row) {
      while($data = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {

           $value=$data[max(id)];
           $value=$value+1;

      }

    }
    else {
      echo mysql_error();
    }
```

Use the retrived data **$value** for your operations

Also change the following too. You had missed **$** sign

```
$res=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO batch(`id`,`phone`) VALUES ($row,'$myArrays')");
```

I also doubts what you mean by this line of code

```
$delete = mysqli_query($db,'insert into to_numbers_hist select * from to_numbers');
```